# test System field on Batch class

Tags: unit-test, batch, code-coverage, knowledge, system-fields

I have a batch that automatically archives any articles with a Status (Fixed) and published for more than 30 days (using a custom setting to verify the number of days).

But I struggle to cover the execute method in my test class
[image]

When doing a system.debug on the article (Knowledge__kav) field **LastPublishedDate** in my test class.
The field returns **null**.
Also, when trying to set a value to **LastPublishedDate**, I have another error:
**field is not writeable LastPublishedDate**.

How can I test LastPublishedDate and increase my test coverage?
Thanks

here is my test class:

```
@isTest
```

public class BatchArticleTest {

```
@testSetup
static void setup() {
    Account acct = new Account(Name = 'test Account');
    insert acct;
    
    Case c = new Case(Status = 'New', AccountId = acct.Id, Type = 'Feature');
    insert c;
    
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'test contact');
    insert con;
    
    //Create article
    Knowledge__kav kav = new Knowledge__kav(Title = 'test', UrlName = 'test', Related_Problem__c = c.Id, Affecting__c = 'test',
                                            Known_Error_Status__c = 'In Review');
                                                                           
    insert kav;
    System.debug('kav ' +kav);
    
    Known_Error_Subscription__c kes = new Known_Error_Subscription__c(Contact__c = con.Id, KnowledgeKA__c = kav.KnowledgeArticleId,
                                                                      Article_Status__c = kav.Known_Error_Status__c, 
                                                                      Article_Title__c = kav.Title);
    insert kes;        
       
}

 // test BatchArticleArchive
 @isTest static void archiveTest() {
    //test PublishingService Class to publish article
    Knowledge__kav kav = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId, LastPublishedDate FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Title = 'test'];
    String articleId = kav.KnowledgeArticleId;
    System.debug('articleId ' +articleId);
    KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(articleId,true);
    
    //test custom setting
    DaysToArchive__c setting = new DaysToArchive__c();
    setting.Name = 'test Setting';
    setting.Number_of_Days__c = 1;
    insert setting;
     
    Double dbl = setting.Number_of_Days__c;
    
    //test PublishingService Class to archive article
    System.debug('LastPublishedDate ' +kav.LastPublishedDate);
    KbManagement.PublishingService.archiveOnlineArticle(kav.knowledgeArticleId,null);
     
    Test.startTest();
    BatchArticleArchive batchArchv = new BatchArticleArchive();
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchArchv);
    Test.stopTest();
}

}
```

Comment: Looks like the query in start is not getting any record. Your code is querying the records where Known error status is Fixed. In test class the record is created with Known error status as In review. Is there any automation which changes that?

Comment: Right, Thanks for pointing this out...
Silly me.
No, no automation